# Android installation of .apk (hybrid app developed with ionic)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, apk

I have a strange behavior, I have developed a hybrid app with ionic, afterwards I have installed it at my mobile with this command:

[image: Installation of apk]

everything was fine, but on my phone I cannot find this app and also cannot find this paths and the file .apk:

```
/data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
pkg: /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run on device -

```
ionic run android
```

This will install application on mobile

Answer (score 0):

1. Testing as a native app

   $ ionic run android

   [More about testing as a native app](https://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html)
2. To generate a release build for Android

   $ cordova build --release android

   [Android Publishing](https://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html)